# Building SlackLogViewer with Qt6 ; issues in QuaZip cmake (pop!_os 22.04)

Tags: linux, build, cmake

I'm a recently converted linux user running Pop!_OS 22.04. I am trying to build [SlackLogViewer](https://github.com/thayakawa-gh/SlackLogViewer) which is a C++ program, using Qt6. In order to do this, I had to build one of the dependencies, [QuaZIP](https://github.com/stachenov/quazip), specifying that I was using Qt6, and placed it in `~/quazip6/` for lack of other ideas.

Now, when running the cmake command for SlackLogViewer, I have encountered several issues.

1. The quazip qt6 cmake file calls for another quazip cmake file but can't find it

```
CMake Error at /home/chaossature/quazip6/quazip/QuaZip-Qt6Config.cmake:29 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    /home/chaossature/quazip6/quazip/QuaZip-Qt6_SharedTargets.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:50 (find_package)
```

Actually, there is a file with such a name, but it's in `/home/chaossature/quazip6/quazip/CMakeFiles/Export/lib/cmake/QuaZip-Qt6-1.4/QuaZip-Qt6_SharedTargets.cmake`. In the cmake file referencing this file, the line in question is `include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/QuaZip-Qt6_SharedTargets.cmake")`.

I am not familiar with cmake, but I tried replacing that path with `${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/CMakeFiles/Export/lib/cmake/QuaZip-Qt6-1.4/QuaZip-Qt6_SharedTargets.cmake` to point at the right file, which did get me rid of the error.

2. Now `QuaZip-Qt6-1.4/QuaZip-Qt6_SharedTargets.cmake` calls for the file located at `/home/chaossature/quazip6/quazip/CMakeFiles/Export/lib/libquazip1-qt6.so.1.4`. Once again such a file exists... But it's actually at the root this time, *ie* in `quazip6/quazip/`, which brings me to believe I broke something by manually changing the first cmake file.
3. I also tried moving the first file to the location the first problematic cmake was looking at instead of changing the cmake file, but this leads to many other path issues.

I believe something is either going on with the way I installed QuaZIP (I'm used to the few cmake files I've seen being in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/` but I'm not sure if I'm supposed to build stuff in there) or with some environment variables, but I'm not proficient enough with linux or cmake files to try more things than what I've listed above. I couldn't find any similar issues on the github pages of these 2 programs, which leads me to believe the problem is between my chair and my monitor...